# CSS and targeting: img "title=this thing here" attribute

Tags: html, css

Can CSS be used to change the title attribute in this img tag to something more pleasant than P10305...? All the images I need to target are in tables (as shown below)

I would like to change all image title attribute in a website to the name of the company. Is it possible?

```
<td><img border="0" title="THIS THING HERE" src="http://the website I'm working on.jpg" /></td>
```

Many thanks
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with CSS, as CSS only affects styles. What you're asking for is a content change.

The change you want *is* possible with Javascript, however. If you happen to be using Prototype, it's pretty easy:

```
$$('td img').each( function( image ) { image.title = "Company Name" } )
```

jQuery should make this similarly easy too.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

That can be slimmed down a bit:

```
$('td img').attr('title', 'value');
```

jQuery will select all `img` inside a `td` and apply that attribute, no reason to have a `.each` in there.

Answer (score 1):

not using strict css.  However jQuery, and other javascript methods can be used to select that image and change it's title attribute.

```
$('td img').each(function() { $(this).attr('title', 'value') });
```

gives you a rough idea of how to use jquery to do this.

Check out the documentation to get a better idea: http://docs.jquery.com/

Comment: I've chosen the first reply as the answer. Not because your was not as good, it's just that I don't know JQuery and therefore am not able to say who has written the best JQuery, so in order to close it I've chosen the first reply.

Comment: First as in newest (mine was the first reply)?  Sidenote, his isn't using JQuery, it's using prototype.